# Compile only one .env file to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have 3 different npm processes:

```
"startdev": "cross-env PROJECT_ENV=development grunt",
"startstage": "cross-env PROJECT_ENV=staging grunt",
"startprod": "cross-env PROJECT_ENV=production grunt"
```

Gruntfile:

```
    var environment = process.env.PROJECT_ENV
    ts: {
        options:{
            rootDir: "src"
        },
        dev : {
            src: ["**/*.ts", "!node_modules/**/*.ts"],
            outDir: "out",
            watch: "src",
            options:{
                module: "commonjs"
            }
```

My environment variables:

```
src/config/.envDevelopment
src/config/.envStaging 
src/config/.envProduction
```

How can I make grunt compile only one environment variable based on the environment passed to cross-env, to .env in the compiled project?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to somehow parse your enviroment string. This might be a solution:

```
var capitalizedEnvironment = environment.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + environment.slice(1);
```

To write the complete path:

```
'path/to/common/folder/' + '.env' + capitalizedEnvironment
```

Comment: This should go into the src property instead of outDir, no?

Comment: Probably, i didn't give so much attention to this. I just thought your problem was to write a custom path for each environment. I've edited my answer... does it help you somehow?